# Random Forest, SVM model giving 100% accuracy for Binary Classification (except neural network)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, python, random-forest

I have a dataset of size (140,000, 10) containing 1 dependent variable. I used MinMax scaler on independent variables. For the target value, there is a class imbalance of 94% 0's and 6% 1's. Used RandomOverSampler for oversampling.

When I run a neural network model on my dataset, it gives me the following plot:
[image: Accuracy and Loss plot]

With a testing accuracy of 96.34%

This is my neural network:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(5, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001),
                       activation='relu', input_shape=(10,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(5, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.001),
                       activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001), 
                       activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_over, y_over, epochs=25, batch_size=100, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True, verbose=1)
```

I have added regularizers to input and hidden layers to prevent overfitting.

On using a Random Forest Classifier and SVM, I get 100% accuracies for training as well as testing. Is something wrong with my data? How do I solve this?

Comment: Could be a genuine difference between models, could be one model being not optimally trained, could be a mistake in preparing the training / test data (e.g. accidentally leaving in the outcome as a predictor for the RF/SVM, including the test data in the training data or something like that).

Comment: So is this plot for neural network correct? Or is it overfitting?

Comment: Leakage is always the first thought. Are the rows in your dataset independent from each other? Or are they correlated somehow (e.g. some rows share some common source, like samples from the same patient)? And are there definitely no features in `X` that encode information about the target in some subtle way?

Comment: I calculated the target variable on the basis of weighted average of the remaining features. If the weighted average crosses a threshold value, the target is 1, otherwise 0.